# WPF ResourceDictionary and DynamicResource

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

i am new to WPF so maybe this will be "noob" question but i can't find answer to it (and it seems so easy)...

well i am programing WPF app and i want to use smth similar to css for webpages, so i found ResourceDictionary and tried to use it...

I have main window in which i create Frame and on click some UserControl is loaded to that same Frame.I include my ResourceDictionary (root/style/Styles.xaml) to my main window like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="styles" Source="style/Styles.xaml" />
</Window.Resources>
```

in which i have:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style x:Key="ProductsRequired" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="28" />
    ...
```

I don't use it on my main window but want to use it on my UserControls, which are loaded to that main window and i try to use it like this:

```
<Label Name="product1" Style="{DynamicResource ProductsRequired}"  />
```

Warning i am getting all the time is: The resource "ProductsRequired" could not be resolved.

I even tried including Styles to my UserControl

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary x:Key="styles" Source="../style/Styles.xaml" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and nothing happens...

Well my question is long but i wanted to be clear... :)

P.S. all that logic works in C# code btw

```cs
private ResourceDictionary myStyles = new ResourceDictionary();
Style ProductsRequired = myStyles["ProductsRequired"] as Style;
product1.Style = ProductsRequired;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't do, you add a resource dictionary *as* a resource when you need to add it *to* the resources, it cannot be accessed like this. You need to add it to the [`MergedDictionaries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.mergeddictionaries.aspx) *(See MSDN for usage examples!)*.

Answer (score 1):

are you referencing the correct assembly?
for example:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/SecurityManagerResources;component/DictionarySecurityResources.xaml"   />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="style/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: i did that before and it didn't work like it doesn't now... :( i don't know what i am doing wrong... And i cant use other resources if i use that...